# Post inside fpdf ... help

Tags: php, web, fpdf, fpdi

Is this possible?

`$pdf->setSourceFile**('Write(0, "h.pfd")')**;` --- it gives this error: FPDF error: Cannot open Write(0, "h.pfd") !

Is there any way to integrate a write inside fpdf?

I just want Post inside `setSourceFile()` fpdi...

any ideas?

--correction ')

Comment: Your syntax is wrong and confusing.

Comment: When you say Post, what do you mean, `$_POST` variables?

Answer (score 0):

already tried? `$pdf->setSourceFile('Write(0, "h.pfd")');`